# Javascript array of objects get distinct data with merge data

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Object :

```
[
        {
            "class_name": "12",
            "bacth": "G",
            "subjects": [
                "Mathematics"
            ]
        },
        {
            "class_name": "12",
            "bacth": "G",
            "subjects": [
                "Physics"
            ]
        },
        {
            "class_name": "11",
            "bacth": "G",
            "subjects": [
                "Physics"
            ]
        }
]
```

I want to remove the duplicate value of classs_name, batch & push different subject data in one array object.

I want to get below output :

```
[
        {
            "class_name": "12",
            "bacth": "G",
            "subjects": [
                "Mathematics","Physics"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "class_name": "11",
            "bacth": "G",
            "subjects": [
                "Physics"
            ]
        }
]
```

I have tried below Code but cant get expected Output:

```
var _unArray = []; // new array without duplicate
    arr.forEach(function(item) { // loop through array which contain duplicate
      // if item is not found in _unArray it will return empty array
       var isPresent = _unArray.filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.class_name === item.class_name && elem.bacth === item.bacth
      })
      if (isPresent.length == 0) { 
        _unArray.push(item)
      }
    })
    console.log(_unArray)
```

Comment: great! what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: I edited my question with code that tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, simply need to push the *subject* to the corresponding *class_name* in *else* condition:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "class_name": "12",
    "bacth": "G",
    "subjects": [
        "Mathematics","Computers"
    ]
  },
  {
    "class_name": "12",
    "bacth": "G",
    "subjects": [
        "Physics", "English"
    ]
  },
  {
    "class_name": "11",
    "bacth": "G",
    "subjects": [
        "Physics"
    ]
  }
]

var _unArray = []; // new array without duplicate
arr.forEach(function(item) { // loop through array which contain duplicate
  // if item is not found in _unArray it will return empty array
   var isPresent = _unArray.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.class_name === item.class_name && elem.bacth === item.bacth
  })
  if (isPresent.length == 0) { 
    _unArray.push(item)
  }
  else {
   _unArray.find(x => x.class_name === item.class_name).subjects.push(...item.subjects);
  }
})
console.log(_unArray);
```

Comment: if multiple subjects has come, it's joining with coma.
for example arr[0] = {
    "class_name": "12",
    "bacth": "G",
    "subjects": [
        "Mathematics","english"
    ]
  }

Comment: @Bijus, I have updated the answer by replacing `.push(item.subjects)` with `.push(...item.subjects)`, please check:)